# pd.cut cannot used for range in negative value

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use the pd.cut for range between -10 to 0.

My code:

```
pd.cut(df, [for i in range( 0,-10,-1)])
```

Error:

```
"bins must increase monotonically"
```

Is there a way to have the bins be like this expected output:

```
[-1,-2], [-2,-3], [-3,-4]...[-9,-10]
```

Comment: Doesn’t that list comprehension cause a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If df is 1 dimensional**:

```
pd.cut(df, [i for i in range( -10,0,1)],right=False)
```

if df is a DataFrame you need select a column/row or pass **1 dimensional array**:

```
pd.cut(df[col], [i for i in range( -10,0,1)],right=False)
```